# Sms receiver for android 7 nougat or higher

Tags: android

How do I receive and read SMS through Broadcast Receivers on Android version 7 or 8?

The tutorials I followed did not work on versions 7 and higher.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcast" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="5822" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**app gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.prixwerkz.smsreceiver"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your manifest code and your app gradle

Comment: Please chechout my manifest and app gradle

Answer (score 0):

Because your targetSdkVersion = 26, by default all your permission set as not allowed and when you don't have RECEIVE_SMS permission your broadcast doesn't work.So you have to option:
1. set your targetSdkVersion under 23 
Or
2. manage permssion on runtime.

As android official site say:

> If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the user isn't notified of any app permissions at install time. Your app must ask the user to grant the dangerous permissions at runtime

find more information in [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) link